# Overflow for left and right?

Tags: css, overflow

I have heard of `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` but haven't heard of anything that you can control it on the left or right.

**Edit:** What I am trying to do is make sure nothing overflows on the right side of the content, but I want overflow allowed on the left side as I have an image that has a css box shadow applied and it's not showing unless I show the overflow.

Is there anything like that available?

Comment: How would you expect that to work? What should happen to the content that overflows the left side when the box is scrolled?

Comment: @BoltClock I don't want a scroll; it would just be visible.

Comment: maybe try fiddling with 'direction: rtl;' on the container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing like controlling the overflow left/right or the placement of the scrollbar (with pure css). The only thing is, that with switching the text-direction from `LTR` to `RTL` the placement of the scrollbar also changes.

EDIT: after clarifying your question: You can't hide overflow only on one side, but not the other. The only easy fix I see at the moment is to adjust the width of the parent-container (e.g. by putting some padding-left).

Comment: Adding padding/margin doesn't work in my situation as then the image is out of alignment with the rest of the content.

Comment: @Brett If you add the padding to the parent container, it is applied to all elements inside, not only the image...

Comment: Sorry, I thought you meant the container of the image itself, not the container of everything.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking if there's a way to place the scrollbar on the left using CSS. If so, no there's not.

Answer (score 0):

Could you specify the question a bit more?
`overflow-x` will set the overflow for the left and right sides, if that is what you are asking.`

EDIT: Well after editing your question, I understand what are you trying to do. How about applying a larger margin-left, to the container div?

Comment: I tried adding a `margin-left` go it, but it didn't look right as it wasn't lined up with the rest of the content.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a header image that had text embedded in the image that needed to be visible at all screen sizes, which meant that the `overflow: hidden` property needed to occur on both the left and right of the image (by default, it only hid the right side of the image as the screen got smaller)

What I ended up doing was having the image set to `position: absolute`, and then I used media queries to position the image to the left a negative number of pixels (like so):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 899px) { 
    left: -90px;
}
```